# Remove Blank rows from csv c#

Tags: c#, csv

id like to remove/skip these highlighted rows in the image below so they would not  appear on the csv file anymore. as you can see below it display the two rows as (,,) because the rows are empty.

as you can also see in the code i tried to used string.Empty in both method but did not seem to get anywhere as i am not really sure on how to do this.

Any suggestions

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Santander .csv");
        var fileContents = ReadFile(filePath);
        foreach (var line in fileContents)
        {
            if (!line.Equals(String.Empty))
                continue;
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    } 

    public static IList<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();
        var target = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
                 .ToList();
        foreach (string currentLine in target)
        {
            if( !currentLine.Equals( String.Empty ) )
            {
                continue;
            }


        }

         File.WriteAllLines(fileName, target);

        return results.ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove the row if any of the columns is empty or blank?

Comment: if possible but ideally only column1 and column2 are main concern

Comment: The line would not be empty because it has columns 3 and 4.. even id they were all empty youd have ",,," as as csv string..

Comment: yeah you right, that is the process which i want

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you want to test just first and second columns:

```
public static IList<string> ReadFile(string fileName) {
  var target = File
    .ReadLines(fileName)
    .Where(line => line
       .Split(',')
       .Take(2)
       .All(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)))
    .ToList();

  File.WriteAllLines(fileName, target);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: yes that all i want because all the other rows in contains data which i would like display

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the rows by splitting each row with `,` and comparing first two columns.

```
var nonEmptyLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
                        .Where(x=> !x.Split(',')
                                     .Take(2)
                                     .Any(cell=> string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell))
                                     // use `All` if you want to ignore only if both columns are empty.  
                         ).ToList();

File.WriteAllLines(fileName, nonEmptyLines);
```

Comment: your code seems to work, however it removed rows 3 and 4 in column 3 and 4 which contains. i would also like these to be displayed too