# Deleting empty rows and columns from a CSV file - C#

Tags: c#

I would like to "clean" a CSV file:

- deleting empty rows
- deleting empty columns

The rows or columns are not completely empty, they have, for example:
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",
(in a row form)
OR 
"","","","","","","","","","",
(in a row form)
OR

"",

"",

"",

"",

"",

"",

"",

(in a columns form)

These rows or columns can be anywhere in the CSV file.

What I have so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string sourceFile = @"XXXXX.xlsx";
            string worksheetName = "Sample";
            string targetFile = @"C:\Users\xxxx\xls_test\XXXX.csv";

            // Creates the CSV file based on the XLS file
            ExcelToCSVCoversion(sourceFile, worksheetName, targetFile);

            // Manipulate the CSV: Clean empty rows
            DeleteEmptyRoadFromCSV(targetFile);
        }

        static void ExcelToCSVCoversion(string sourceFile, string worksheetName,
            string targetFile)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sourceFile
                + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""";
            OleDbConnection connection = null;
            StreamWriter writer = null;
            OleDbCommand command = null;
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;

            try
            {
                // Represents an open connection to a data source. 
                connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();

                // Represents a SQL statement or stored procedure to execute  
                // against a data source. 
                command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + worksheetName + "$]",
                                            connection);
                // Specifies how a command string is interpreted. 
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                // Implements a TextWriter for writing characters to the output stream 
                // in a particular encoding. 
                writer = new StreamWriter(targetFile);
                // Represents a set of data commands and a database connection that are  
                // used to fill the DataSet and update the data source. 
                dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                for (int row = 0; row < dataTable.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    string rowString = "";
                    for (int column = 0; column < dataTable.Columns.Count; column++)
                    {
                        rowString += "\"" + dataTable.Rows[row][column].ToString() + "\",";
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine(rowString);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("The excel file " + sourceFile + " has been converted " +
                                  "into " + targetFile + " (CSV format).");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
                connection.Dispose();
                command.Dispose();
                dataAdapter.Dispose();
                writer.Close();
                writer.Dispose();
            }
        }

        static void DeleteEmptyRoadFromCSV(string fileName)
        {
            //string nonEmptyLines = @"XXXX.csv";
            var nonEmptyLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
                        .Where(x => !x.Split(',')
                                     .Take(2)
                                     .Any(cell => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell))
                         // use `All` if you want to ignore only if both columns are empty.  
                         ).ToList();

        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, nonEmptyLines);
        }
```

Finally, I tried to use the ideas from:
[Remove Blank rows from csv c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971272/remove-blank-rows-from-csv-c-sharp) . But my ouput is not changing at all.

Any help is welcome!

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you re-inventing the wheel?  That's a lot of work when you could use a text file parser which would be much more robust also.

Comment: Also, `File.ReadAllLines` is probably dangerous unless you know for sure you are dealing with small files.

Comment: Linq can probably help here, where you can skip empty rows/columns. It may also help clean up your code a bit.

Comment: Hey @rory.ap,
I will take a look at text file parser!
thanks

Comment: Hi @GibralterTop,
Actually, my file maximum 50 lines, this is why I choose ReadAllLines but I will keep in mind your tip. thank you

Comment: Have you looked into a CSV parser/writer library like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ ? This one in particular can help you create formatted output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delete columns/rows from table before saving csv.
Method is not tested, but you should get the concept.

```
 static void ExcelToCSVCoversion(string sourceFile, string worksheetName,
       string targetFile)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sourceFile
            + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""";
        OleDbConnection connection = null;
        StreamWriter writer = null;
        OleDbCommand command = null;
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;

        try
        {
            // Represents an open connection to a data source. 
            connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            // Represents a SQL statement or stored procedure to execute  
            // against a data source. 
            command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + worksheetName + "$]",
                                        connection);
            // Specifies how a command string is interpreted. 
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            // Implements a TextWriter for writing characters to the output stream 
            // in a particular encoding. 
            writer = new StreamWriter(targetFile);
            // Represents a set of data commands and a database connection that are  
            // used to fill the DataSet and update the data source. 
            dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            var emptyRows =
                dataTable.Select()
                    .Where(
                        row =>
                            dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                .All(column => string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[column].ToString()))).ToArray();
            Array.ForEach(emptyRows, x => x.Delete());

            var emptyColumns =
                dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                    .Where(column => dataTable.Select().All(row => string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[column].ToString())))
                    .ToArray();
            Array.ForEach(emptyColumns, column => dataTable.Columns.Remove(column));
            dataTable.AcceptChanges();

            for (int row = 0; row < dataTable.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                string rowString = "";
                for (int column = 0; column < dataTable.Columns.Count; column++)
                {
                    rowString += "\"" + dataTable.Rows[row][column].ToString() + "\",";
                }
                writer.WriteLine(rowString);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("The excel file " + sourceFile + " has been converted " +
                              "into " + targetFile + " (CSV format).");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
            connection.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            dataAdapter.Dispose();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey
This sounds a good idea but I was not able to run.
On the part:

emptyRows.ForEach(x => x.Delete());
and
emptyColumns.ForEach(column => dataTable.Columns.Remove(column));

I keep having the error: "There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'action' of 'Array.ForEach,T>(T[], Action <T>)'"   -> Exceptions: ArgumentNullExpection

I tried, with no success:
                foreach (var etRows in emptyRows)
                {
                    (x => x.Delete());
                }

Comment: I have updated ForEach statements. Please check now.

Comment: It is working!
I had the idea that working with the XLS, instead of CSV, would be much more complicated but with your solution, it is working!

I really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following query is working.I am getting all the rows:

```
var nonEmptyLines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName)
                        .Where(x => !x.Split(',')
                                     .Take(2)
                                     .Any(cell => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell))
                         // use `All` if you want to ignore only if both columns are empty.  
                         ).ToList();
```

I think you can use something as:

```
  var nonEmptyLines = File.ReadAllLines(File).
                        SkipWhile(cell=>{var arr=cell.Split(',');if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell)){
                            return true;
                        }
                            else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        });
```

Comment: Hey
I tried both;
They are executing fine but the output (CSV) remains the same.
The debugging can be seen:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B98UpTa2n4XbeHZtOHU2cVotUms?usp=sharing  (Sorry, but my image attachments never work here)